# IAM policy to allow access to DynamoDB console for specific tables

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

Is it possible to create an AWS IAM policy that provides access to the DynamoDB console only for specific tables? I have tried:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt0000000001",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                "dynamodb:ListTables",
                <other actions>
            ], 
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:<region>:<account>:table/FooTable",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:<region>:<account>:table/BarTable"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

but for a user with this policy attached, the DynamoDB tables list says `Not Authorized` (as it does when no policy is attached).

Setting `"Resource"` to `"*"` and adding a new statement like below lets the user perform `<other actions>` on `FooTable` and `BarTable`, but they can also see all other tables in the tables list.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt0000000001",
            "Action": [
                <other actions>
            ], 
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:<region>:<account>:table/FooTable",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:<region>:<account>:table/BarTable"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt0000000002",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                "dynamodb:ListTables"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is it about the Sid? Is this arbitrary?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry for the bad news, but the AWS Management Console requires both `DescribeTable` and `ListTables` permissions against the whole of DynamoDB in order to operate correctly.

However, there is a small workaround... You can give Console users a URL that takes them directly to the table, and operates fine for viewing and adding items, etc.

Just copy the URL from a user that has correct permissions, eg:

```
https://REGION.console.aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/home?region=REGION#explore:name=TABLE-NAME
```

Comment: And thanks for the thought, although they can still get to the DynamoDB console from that link.

Comment: Can't find a specific reference to this in the documentation, but I experimented with your policy and confirmed that both those permissions are required for the "Table List" page of the console to function correctly.

Comment: This now works me has: https://console.aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/home?region=REGION#tables:selected=TABLENAME

Answer (score 0):

I found that apart from DynamoDB, [users need to have wildcard permissions for **CloudWatch** and **SNS**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/using-identity-based-policies.html). (Consider [*"Example 5: Set Up Permissions Policies for Separate Test and Production Environments"*](http://web.archive.org/web/20170216235241/http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/using-identity-based-policies.html#access-policy-examples-for-sdk-cli.example5)).

You may add `AmazonDynamoDBReadOnlyAccess` to your predefined policies.

Comment: The referenced ressource was updated and no longer contained the mentioned example, so i added an archive link.