# Deny Access to a DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam, aws-policies

I try to create a policy which denies access to a dynamodb table.

I've added ReadOnlyAccess (full) and I want that the user can not read/use/put data in one table

The policy looks like this

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:BatchGet*",
                "dynamodb:DescribeStream",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                "dynamodb:Get*",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:BatchWrite*",
                "dynamodb:CreateTable",
                "dynamodb:Delete*",
                "dynamodb:Update*",
                "dynamodb:PutItem"
            ],
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:xx-xx-xx:xxxxxxx:table/some-name"
        }
    ]
}
```

The user can now not check data in the some-name table which is fine but when I list the tables I see a load of random "failed to load" tables. I can click on them and access the data but I don't want to see failed to load (except then possible for the some-name table).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide an example of these "failed to load" messages? A screenshot, or the exact message and where it appears? You might also be able to use AWS CloudTrail to see which API calls were made by the console that are being denied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot find a primary source, but judging from answers on this question [IAM policy to allow access to DynamoDB console for specific tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30407179/441264), the "dynamodb:DescribeTable" permissions might always be required for all tables for the console to work properly.

I guess it makes sense though, since I dont think the returned tables from "ListTables" can be restricted, and if the console execute a "DescribeTable" on the restricted table, it will get an error.